# Collection was modified; impossible to perform the operation listings on socket.Receive

Tags: .net, sockets, f#

When I am doing :

```
Array.Clear(Core.arrayRead,0 , 1024)
let cBytes = Core.socket.Receive(Core.arrayRead, 1024, SocketFlags.None)
```

First time (with empty array) it works good, but next time when I am clearing my array to receive new bytes I've got this error : **Collection was modified; impossible to perform the operation listings**

Is it still clearing ? or what ? How can I fix it ?

more code :

```
try
    Core.listPos |> Seq.iter /> fun op ->
        Core.socket.Send(op.Buffer) |> ignore
        Array.Clear(Core.arrayRead,0 , 1024)
        let cBytes = Core.socket.Receive(Core.arrayRead, 1024, SocketFlags.None) // error ->
        if  cBytes > 0 then
            Core.WorkPos cBytes
with
    | :? SocketException as e   -> Core.output.Add ("Ошибка протокола связи : "    + e.Message)
    | _ as e                    -> Core.output.Add ("Ошибка : "                    + e.Message) // My error here
```

Comment: Hi, I don't think that this error comes from this two lines of code - can you check the stacktrace of the exception and give the lines mentioned there?

Comment: Yes, I found this strange too. But error is coming right on the Receive string.

Comment: Is setting an arrayRead somehow changeing the Core.listPos? That's the only sense I can get from this (because the Seq.iter <- this can throw such a exception)

Comment: yes, it's my fault. Core.listPos were changed by another thread

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just wanted to conclude, if someon reads this or got a similiar question in the future:

The problem was the Core.listPos collection and the Seq.iter in

```
Core.listPos |> Seq.iter /> fun op ->
   ...
```

not the socket.Receive, because the listPos got changed from another thread.
Seq.iter will (just as foreach in C#) throw such exceptions if the collection changes (most often this is due to some `.Remove` inside the loops-body).

An easy solution would be to write

```
let positions = Core.listPos |> Seq.toArray
positions |> Seq.iter /> fun op -> ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't modify an enumeration while traversing it (foreach). What is the outer code you are using?

Use a `byte[]` to receive data, see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.aspx) for an example.

Comment: Oh, it's truly my fault. I missed Core.listPos was changed in separate thread.